# Examples of when to use "Accessed" in citation and references

Tags: citations, citation-style, website

I once found an example of "Accessed" from or date accessed in citation and references in the current 6th edition of the APA publication manual.  Would somebody please give me a proper example of how to use Accessed to cite and reference a website?  Also the page number in the APA manual would help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, APA uses "retrieved from" for websites [rather than "accessed from"](http://www2.eit.ac.nz/library/OnlineGuides/APA%20Referencing%20Guide.pdf):

> Retrieved [date] from [URL].

It should be noted that dates are only required for frequently changing content; more or less "static" web pages do not need to have a date included, although there is certainly nothing wrong with doing so.

Comment: I would argue that the default for websites should be to assume non-static unless they are explicitly stated to be archival.

Comment: @jakebeal: Fair enough. But I'm trying to distinguish what the APA considers obligatory and what it doesn't.